# Ruby on Rails, json/yml to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I need to pull the data from file/url to some model and then display it on the page. Which format for the data is better - yml or json? And how do I read it and parse to Ruby object?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "better" - only suitability and personal taste.

YAML and JSON are both good choices, but as a generalisation Rubyists tend to use YAML for configuration files and JSON for data transfer over web APIs.

Parsing both of these data types is trivial in Ruby, and Googling these is also trivial.